# Why is Scipy's percentileofscore returning a different result than Excel's PERCENTRANK.INC?

Tags: python, excel-formula, scipy, percentile

I'm running into a strange issue with scipy's `percentileofscore` function.

In Excel, I have the following rows:

```
0
1
3
3
3
3
3
4
6
8
9
11
11
11
12
45
```

Next, I have a column that calculates the percentilerank.inc for each row:

```
=100 * (1-PERCENTRANK.INC($A:$A,A1))
```

The results are as follows:

```
100
94
87
87
87
87
87
54
47
40
34
27
27
27
7
0
```

I then take the same data and put them into an array and calculate the percentilofscore using scipy

```
100 - stats.percentileofscore(array, score, kind='strict')
```

However, my results are as follows:

```
100
94
88
88
88
88
88
56
50
44
38
31
31
31
13
7
```

Here are the results side by side to show the differences:

```
Data    Excel   Scipy
0       100     100
1       94      94
3       87      88
3       87      88
3       87      88
3       87      88
3       87      88
4       54      56
6       47      50
8       40      44
9       34      38
11      27      31
11      27      31
11      27      31
12      7       13
45      0       7
```

There are clearly some differences in the results. Some of them off by 4 digits.

Any thoughts on how to mimic Excel's `PERCENTILERANK.INC` function?

I'm using `scipy 1.0.0`, `numpy 1.13.3`, `python 3.5.2`, `Excel 2016`

*Edit* 
If I do not include the max value of 45, the numbers jive. Could this be how `PERCENTILERANK.INC` works?

Comment: I get `6.25` instead of `0` for the last result with SciPy.

Comment: @user2357112 I had a copy error. I updated it to reflect the correct value. Since I'm casting to an `int()` the result is 7 for me.

Comment: Have you tried to exclude the row with a 0 value in it before sending to scipy?  You should have a look at [this explanation](http://www.real-statistics.com/descriptive-statistics/ranking-function-excel/) which shows the excel functions have interpolation.

Comment: @BrianPendleton I just discovered the issue while you were posting this comment. Thanks for the link for a better explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Excel function `PERCENTILERANK.INC` excludes the max value (in my case 45). Which is why it shows `0` versus `6.25` like `scipy` does.

To rectify this, I modified my function to remove the max values of the array like so:

```
array = list(filter(lambda a: a != max(array), array))

return 100 - int(stats.percentileofscore(array, score, kind='strict'))
```

This gave me the correct results, and all my other tests passed.

Additional information based on Brian Pendleton's comment. Here is a link to the Excel functions explaining [PERCENTILERANK.INC](http://www.real-statistics.com/descriptive-statistics/ranking-function-excel/) as well as other ranking functions. Thanks for this.